# Powershell script fails when run via nant

Tags: powershell, nant, executionpolicy

I have several team members who can't run powershell scripts via nant. When they do, they get the `ExectutionPolicy` (not high enough, still set at the default value). However, they've run  `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in a powershell console, and they can run the powershell scripts directly. Any ideas about what's going wrong?

Comment: do ant runs under the same user account ? If you're script is on a remote folder set execution policy to Bypass

Comment: Nope, everything is local. It also runs fine if run directly. Also, same user is running both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are running on a 64-bit machine, have they set the execution policy for both 32-bit and 64-bit PowerShell? It could be that they set the policy for 64-bit PowerShell and NAnt is firing up 32-bit PowerShell (or vice-versa).  Another way to work around this if you're on at least PowerShell 2.0 is to set the policy when invoking PowerShell e.g.:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ...
```

Comment: oh, I like this approach. Hassle free!